# Jquery determine point spread

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate a point spread to determine a winner.
I have a function that calculates the total number of points based on the scores entered.
I have written a function that should determine the point spread and then apply a label to the winner. However for some reason if the second player gets points after the first and eventually wins the winner label is still applied to the first player.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to go about this?

calculate function

```
function calculate() {
            var arr = [];
            var orr = [];
            var input = "";
            var row1 = 0;
            var row2 = 0;
            $("tbody tr").each(function() {
                row_total = 0;
                $(".score", this).each(function() {
                    row_total += Number($(this).val());
                });
                $(".total", this).val(row_total);
                $(".total", this).each(function() {
                    arr[row1] = $(this).val();
                    row1 += 1;
                });
                $(".status", this).each(function() {
                    orr[row2] = $(this);
                    row2 += 1;
                });
            });

            var spread = Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[1]);

            if (spread >= 5) {
                if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
                    input = orr[0];
                } else if (arr[1] > arr[0]) {
                    input = orr[1];
                }
                alert("arr0:" + arr[0] + '\n' +
                        "arr1:" + arr[1] + '\n' +
                        "orr0:" + orr[0].text() + '\n' +
                        "orr1:" + orr[1].text() + '\n' +
                        "input:" + $(input).text() + '\n');
                var w3 = $(input).html("Winner");
                var w4 = $(input).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
                var w5 = $(input).css('color', 'black');
            }
        }
```

HTML Table

```
<table id="main">
        <tr>
            <td class="r_color">

            </td>
            <td class="r_name">
                Competitor
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                Score 
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                Warnings
            </td>
            <td class="r_total">
                Total
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn_Reset" value="Reset Points"/>
                <input type="button" id="btn_Clear" value="Clear All"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="r_color">
                Red:
            </td>
            <td class="r_name">
                <input type="text" class="name"/>
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                <input class="score" type="number" step="1" min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                <input class="warning" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="3" value="0" />
            </td>
            <td class="r_total">
                <input class="total" type="text" value="0"/>
            </td>
            <td class="status">
                red
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="r_color">
                White:
            </td>
            <td class="r_name">
                <input type="text" class="name"/>
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                <input class="score" type="number" step="1" min="-100" max="100" value="0" />
            </td>
            <td class="r_score">
                <input class="warning" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="3" value="0" />
            </td>
            <td class="r_total">
                <input class="total" type="text" value="0"/>
            </td>
            <td class="status">
                white
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to "guess" the HTML part and just replaced .val() with .html() on lines 5, 7 and 14 because I used  for my scores, totals and statuses (I don't know what you're using).

The HTML part:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="score">10</td>
            <td class="score">10</td>
            <td class="score">5</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
            <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="score">30</td>
            <td class="score">4</td>
            <td class="score">5</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
            <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript part:

```
function calculate() {
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
        row_total = 0;
        $(".score", this).each(function() {
            row_total += Number($(this).html());
        });
        $(".total", this).html(row_total);
    });

    var arr = [];
    var orr = [];
    var row = 0;
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
        $(".total", this).each(function() {
            arr[row] = $(this).html();
            orr[row] = $(this);
            row += 1;
        });
    });

    var spread = Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[1]);

    if (spread >= 5) {
        alert(arr[0] + "|" + arr[1]);
        if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
            var w3 = $(orr[0]).closest('tr').find('.status').html("Winner");
            var w4 = $(orr[0]).closest('tr').find('.status').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
            var w5 = $(orr[0]).closest('tr').find('.status').css('color', 'black');
        } else if (arr[1] > arr[0]) {
            var w3 = $(orr[1]).closest('tr').find('.status').html("Winner");
            var w4 = $(orr[1]).closest('tr').find('.status').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
            var w5 = $(orr[1]).closest('tr').find('.status').css('color', 'black');
        }
    }
}
```

Changing nothing else, your code works, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/JgPvM/1/

Comment: I added my html code I am using html5 number input fields. I also changed up my calculate function to be a bit more code friendly. However I am still having the same problem were the top score is not always labeled the winner

Comment: Works by adding the missing <tbody> (nothing is selected anymore with your  $("tbody tr").each ) and replacing

    arr[row1] = $(this).html();

with

    arr[row1] = $(this).val();

because you're working with an <input class="total">

http://jsfiddle.net/MgxLA/

Comment: In my form I am running the calculate function every time the score changes. If I switch between the 2 fields and add 1 to the first field and 2 to the second consecutively when the spread becomes 5 when field 1 is at 5 and field 2 is at field 10 the first field is labeled as the winner. Even though the second has the greater score.
If I just add to one field then everything works fine.

Comment: Okay, found your bug. At some point, you're comparing strings, and "5" is greater than "10".

    arr[row1] = $(this).val();

should be

    arr[row1] = Number($(this).val());